# How to boot Linux on hard drive from live cd/usb loader

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, live-cd

I have Ubuntu installed on my sda5 partition, however it lacks a bootloader.

I know it is possible to load Grub2 from live cd, press Tab and change boot parameters to boot the system which is on hard drive. But what should I exactly write?

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu ISO, by default, does not come with GRUB as bootloader, but it does have GRUB installed and you can use it to install a bootloader in your main disk. To do it, boot from the Live CD, open a terminal (by hitting Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt

sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt/

sudo chroot /mnt

sudo update-grub

exit
```

Now reboot and your main disk should have a bootloader (GRUB) with the option to boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey, next time you want to edit my code, please know what you're doing.